# what is this shift used in the simplified galil seiferas string match algorithm?

Tags: string, algorithm, string-matching, finite-automata, knuth-morris-pratt

I'm self-studying problem 32-1 in CLRS; part c), presents the following algorithm for string matching:

```
REPETITION-MATCHER(P, T)
  m = P.length
  n = T.length
  k = 1 + ρ'(P)
  q = 0
  s = 0
  while s <= n-m
    if T[s+q+1] == P[q+1]
      q = q+1
      if q==m
        print "Pattern occurs with shift" s
    if q==m or T[s+q+1] != P[q+1]
       s = s+max(1, ceil(q/k))
       q = 0
```

Here, ρ'(P), which is a function of P only, is defined as the largest integer r such that some prefix P[1..i] = y^r, e.g. a substring y repeated r times.

This algorithm appears to be 95 percent similar to the naive brute-force string matcher. However, the one part which greatly confuses me, and which seems to be the centerpiece of the entire algorithm, is the second to last line. Here, q is the number of characters of P matched so far. What is the rationale behind `ceil(q/k)`? It is completely opaque to me. It would have made more sense if that line were something like `s = s + max(1+q, 1+i)`, where i is the length of the prefix that gives rise to ρ'(P).

CLRS claims that this algorithm is due to Galil and Seiferas, but in the [reference](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c681/7d2df4dfeaa121388dc8c8784821e1a6d29d.pdf) they provide, I cannot find anything that resembles the algorithm provided above. It appears that reference contains, if anything, a much more advanced version of what is here. Can someone explain this `ceil(q/k)` value, and/or point me toward a reference that describes this particular algorithm, instead of the more well-known main Galil Seiferas paper?

Comment: Try your option with `aaab` in `aaaab`. Here after first mismatch you are allowed to move forward only by one symbol.

Answer (score 0):

**Example #1:**
Match `aaaa` in `aaaaab`, here `ρ' = 4`. Consider state:

```
aaaa ab
    ^
```

We have a mismatch here, and we want to move forward by one symbol, no more, because we will match full pattern again (last line sets `q` to zero). `q = 4` and `k = 5`, so `ceil(q/k) = 1`, that's all right.

**Example #2:** Match `abcd.abcd.abcd.X` in `abcd.abcd.abcd.abcd.X`. Consider state:

```
abcd.abcd.abcd. abcd.X
               ^
```

We have a mismatch here, and we would like to move forward by five symbols. `q = 15` and `k = 4`, so `ceil(q/k) = 4`. That's ok, it is almost 5, we still can match our pattern. Had we bigger `ρ'`, say 10, we would have `ceil(50/(10+1)) = 5`.

---

Yeh, algorithms skips forward less symbols than KMP does, in case `ρ'=10` its running time is `O(10n+m)` while KMP has `O(n+m)`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the proof of correctness.

let k = ρ'(P) + 1, and ρ'(P) is the largest possible repetition factor out of all the prefixes of P.

Suppose `T[s+1..s+q] = P[1..q]`, and either `q=m` or `T[s+q+1] != P[q+1]`

Then, for 1 <= j <= floor(q/k) (except for the case q=m and m mod k = 0, in which the upper limit must be ceil(m/k)), we have

```
T[s+1..s+j] = P[1..j]
T[s+j+1..s+2j] = P[j+1..2j]
T[s+2j+1..s+3j] = P[2j+1..3j]
...
T[s+(k-1)j+1..s+kj] = P[(k-1)j+1..kj]
```

where not every quantity on every line is equal, since k cannot be a repetition factor, since the largest possible repetition factor out of any prefix of P is k-1.

Suppose we now make a comparison at shift s' = s+j, so that we will make the following comparisons

```
T[s+j+1..s+2j] with P[1..j]
T[s+2j+1..s+3j] with P[j+1..2j]
T[s+3j+1..s+4j] with P[2j+1..3j]
...
T[s+kj+1..s+(k+1)j] with P[(k-1)j+1..kj]
```

We claim that not every comparison can match, e.g. at least *one* of the above "with"s must be replaced with !=. We prove by contradiction. Suppose every "with" above is replaced by =. Then, comparing to the *first* set of comparisons we did, we would immediately have the following:

```
P[1..j] = P[j+1..2j]
P[j+1..2j] = [2j+1..3j]
...
P[(k-2)j+1..(k-1)j] = P[(k-1)j+1..kj]
```

However, this cannot be true, because k is not a repetition factor, hence a contradiction.

Hence, for any 1 <= j <= floor(q/k), testing a new shift s'=s+j is guaranteed to mismatch.

Hence, the smallest shift that is possible to result in a match is s + floor(q/k) + 1 >= ceil(q/k).

Note the code uses ceil(q/k) for simplicity, solely to deal with the case that q = m and m mod k = 0, in which case k * (floor(q/k)+1) would be greater than m, so only ceil(q/k) would do. However, when q mod k = 0 and q < m, then ceil(q/k) = floor(q/k), so is slightly suboptimal, since that shift is guaranteed to fail, and floor(q/k)+1 is the first shift that has any chance of matching.